# How to post a picture card?

Tags: australia, tips-and-tricks, mail

Summary:
Recently went on a road trip to Adelaide, bought one of these picture postcards to send to someone.

Question: 
This is the first time I'm sending one of these so sorry if it's a stupid question, but how do you send this? Do i need an envelope or can i stick a stamp somewhere (cant find where) . And where can I write a message?

[image: card front]

[image: card back]

**Edit:**
Just an update ,Australia does not provide special postage stamps for picture cards, it costs same as a normal letter. I've sent the card, thanks.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You don't need an envelope - these cards are intended to be sent as is.

On the reverse of the card there is a blank area to the left: your message goes here.

The address goes in the lined area to the right.

The stamp goes in the top right corner above the address. Some cards have a rectangle printed there to indicate the right place. Your card has a barcode printed there: just stick your stamp(s) over it.

Comment: Also one should include the country with the address if sending international. Of course this particular question is someone on a "road trip" in Australia which likely does not include crossing any borders, but future readers in other locales may wish to keep this in mind. Additionally postage for stamps may be less than standard postage, something to keep in mind when buying stamps.

Comment: @NigelFds Note that many postal services have special cheaper stamps meant specifically for postcards.

Comment: @chrylis ohh didnt know that .. Thanks mate

Comment: Note however that the cheaper postcard fee also often means much slower service (or at least it used to, haven’t sent a postcard in a while). It can be worth it to pay for “air mail”, which can sometimes reduce transit time from weeks to days.

Comment: It's common for a traveller on a few weeks holiday abroad to arrive home before his postcards do!  This probably doesn't matter too much :-)

Comment: International tip, (not sure about Australia,) ask in the post card shop whether they sell stamps or where to buy them if they do not sell them. Stamps sellers will often ask where you want to send the card to, if they do not, tell them which country.

Comment: A tip I learnt as a child: if you plan to write a lot, apply the stamps BEFORE writing. That way, you can write around the stamp too.

Answer (score 52):

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

If sending within the same country, you can omit the country name in the address.

When sending to a different country, you can write the address (except the "Country" part) in the destination country language.

---

To address the "Country" controversy that ensued in comments, I offer [these guidelines](https://auspost.com.au/sending/check-sending-guidelines/addressing-guidelines) from none other but Australia Post themselves, which only mention country in the context of international mail:

> The last line should contain the place name or post office of delivery, state or territory abbreviation and postcode. This line should be printed in capitals without punctuation or underlining, with the postcode put last
>
> For international mail, the country name should be in capitals on the bottom line

Comment: @David he clearly stated that between different countries you should not ommit the country name.

Comment: Indeed he did, but without a country identifier there's a risk that the sorting in the country of deposit will route the card to the other country. Why would one want to take this chance?

Comment: @David which is "THE other country", when the country name is absent?

Comment: @mustaccio The other country(ies) that have towns or cities of the same name, known by the sorting clerk.

Comment: @David Even if we assume existence of an actual _sorting clerk_ in the XXI century Australia, do you really expect such a clerk in Adelaide SA, looking at the postcard saying "Sydney" and no country (and an Australian-looking postal code), forward it to Sydney, Vanuatu, or to some other of the Sydneys outside Australia? How would he or she choose the "other" country?

Comment: Case in point: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WumR2qpqP8

Comment: As to similar names, you're right: a brief sojurn in place-name lists from the two countries didn't reveal anything closer than Collingwood/Collinton, or something like that. Of course if the country name isn't needed, and one has the postal code, the city name isn't needed either. And if the sorting is all mechanical, then of course there's no possibility of error. I cheerfully surrender.

Comment: I've never seen country listed on domestic mail, and the presence of a local-format postal code will usually make it unambiguous.

Comment: I have never seen country in domestic mail either....

Comment: Having sent hundreds of letters from Barcelona (Catalonia) to Barcelona without writing the country - that was when business were run on paper - I can't tell that none of them got neither to Barcelona in Venezuela nor Barcelona in the Philippines nor to any of the other Barcelonas (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcelona_(disambiguation)) that exist over the world.

Comment: @David: Like others I am very confused. If an address is valid for the current country and has no other country labelled why would anybody route it to a different country? I have never seen a letter addressed to the same country including a country name and I don't see any reason that different rules would be applied to a postcard. Sending something to a country to which it isn't addressed just seems like gross incompetence.

Comment: Thanks all. The more I muse on this, and actually consider how my incoming mail appears and how I address my own in-country mail, the more I agree: in-country mailing does not require the country name. I have deleted my first comment. My downvote has been reversed; being correct, IMO, the answer should stand.

Answer (score 8):

Postcards are for direct mailing and *often* enjoy a lower postage rate than envelopes. They are more vulnerable to damage and marking, but that, and the stamps and cancellation, may add to the charm.

The stamp goes in the **upper right.  It must be on the same side as the address**.  This, and some fluorescent dye on the stamp,  is used by the sorting machines to *face* (orient) the mail piece, so the machine can OCR-read the address, which can succeed *if you print neatly.  This will greatly speed up processing*.

In the US at least, postcards are First Class aka Priority Mail. And will be handled at that speed, except for the handwriting issue.

This is not obvious, but they put their ugly barcode exactly where the stamp must go.  This is to not waste space and to help hide the barcode.  The local post office may be able to advise which stamp or combination of stamps will fully cover it. Nothing more romantic than a jumble of mixed foreign stamps, you might even do that gratuitously!

To move internationally, certain specific stamps *may* be required. Extras / overpaying postage is harmless on postcards, but don't do it on packages.

The address goes on the provided lines.  If there are two sets of lines, the lower or right one is for the main address.

The return address should be smaller, above,  and if possible to the left.  The return address is meant to be the sender's, but who would know?

If you hand walk it into a post office, some clerks will cheerfully cancel it "old school" for the classic look.